A tree edge splits a tree in two parts.
Let $T$ be a tree and $u,v,w$ be vertices of $T$, where $v$ and $w$ are neighbors. $E(T)$ is the set of edges of $T$.
It is known that paths in trees are unique, so let $P_{u,v}$ be the path from $u$ to $v$ and $P_{u,w}$ the path from $u$ to $w$. Let $e\in E(T)$ join $v$ and $w$.
Show that either $e \not \in E(P_{u,v})$ or $e \not \in E(P_{u,w})$, i.e. $e$ cannot be an edge of both $P_{u,v}$ and $P_{u,w}$.
My thoughts so far:
The basic idea is that $e \in E(P_{u,v}) \cap E(P_{u,w})$ implies we go back a step in one of the two paths, leading to a contradiction.
How to get there?
When $e\in E(P_{u,v})$, then we know that the second to last vertex of $P_{u,v}$ is $w$.
Similarly $e\in E(P_{u,w})$ implies the second to last vertex of $P_{u,w}$ is $v$.

Can you define $E(T)$? Is this the edges of the tree, or all paths of the tree? Likewise for $ E( P_{u, v})$.

I added the definitions. Its the edges.

So you want $u, v$ to be neighbors? If so, it's better to make that explicit when defined initially, instead of subsequently saying that $e \in E(T)$.

$v$ and $w$, but yes. I added it.

Deleting edge $e$ leaves a graph $T-e$ with two connected components: one containing $v$, and one containing $w$. To see this:

It cannot still be connected, because if there were a $v-w$ path in $T-e$, then there would have been two such paths in $T$. So there is at least a connected component containing $v$ and another connected component containing $w$.
$T-e$ cannot have a connected component containing neither $v$ nor $w$. Suppose one exists, and call it $C$; then there are no edges leaving $C$ in $T-e$. But neither of $e$'s endpoints is in $C$, so there are no edges leaving $C$ in $T$, and therefore $T$ is still not connected, contradiction.

Vertex $u$ must be in one of these components, which means that there is either a $u-v$ path or a $u-w$ path in $T-e$.
If there is a $u-v$ path in $T-e$, it is exactly $P_{uv}$, meaning that $e \notin E(P_{uv})$. Similarly, if there is a $u-w$ path in $T-e$, it is exactly $P_{uw}$, meaning that $e \notin E(P_{uw})$.

then I need to prove that "Deleting edge $e$ leaves a graph $T−e$ with two connected components"

@SK19 I've added the details. (This is, in an ideal scenario, the reason we ask for context in questions; so that it is clear what can be assumed and what needs proof in an answer. In practice, it's sometimes hard to predict in advance what will be relevant.)

Diagram :

Let the tree have the Nodes $U,V,W$ , with Edges marked $1,2,3,4$
Path $P(U,V)$ is marked in Purple
Path $P(U,W)$ is marked in Blue
Path $P(V,W)$ is marked in Green
Here Edge $E=1$ is in neither $P(U,V)$ nor $P(U,W)$ nor $P(V,W)$. Likewise for Edge $E=2$.
When the there no common Edge to $P(U,V)$ & $P(U,W)$ , then the Claim holds : Edge $E=3$ can not occur in union of those two Paths. Likewise for Edge $E=4$
Hence let us move Node $U$ a little higher , Eg to the root. New Edges get included in $P(U,V) \cup (U,W)$
The Purple Path & the Blue Path will get extended with the Dotted lines to make up $P(U,V) \cap (U,W)$ which are the common Edges.
The Green Path , ignorant of $U$ , will remain unaltered : $[ P(U,V) \cup (U,W) ] - [ P(U,V) \cap (U,W) ]$.
Hence the Claim will continue to hold.

Assume $P_{u,v}$ contains that edge $e$. Then as you wrote, the second to last vertex of $P_{u,v}$ is $w$. But that means $P_{u,v}=P_{u,w}+e$ because as you wrote the paths in trees are unique. Now $P_{u,w}$ cannot contain $e$ anymore or else $P_{u,v}$ would contain $e$ twice, violating the path property!
